# c# winforms: DataGridView scrollbar not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to C# and Winforms..

I am having a **problem with my scrollbar in DataGridView**.

The ***vertical scrollbar image does not show***, **BUT** you can scroll the grid using the using the mouse's scroll wheel.

What should be done to properly handle my scrollbar in DataGridView. I have read several solutions but none of them were able to solve this issue. All of my columns already have `Frozen` Property set to `false`, and I have set the `AutoSizeMode` of the problematic column to `AllCells`. But didn't worked..

Comment: Please be more specific: What have you tried already?

Comment: myDataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Auto

Comment: @stakx: I have editted my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply,

```
myDataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all columns should be set to frozen EXCEPT the first column of dataGridView, then the scroll bar will appear.